# Finding the transcendental equation and the form of the eigenfunctions given a regular Sturm-Liouville problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series, transcendental-equations

Consider the Sturm-Liouville problem:
[image: equation image]
where h > 0.

I need to determine the transcendental equation for the eigenvalues, as well as the "form" of the eigenfunctions. I tried finding the Fourier coefficients, as that has been the typical class process, but I don't know how that relates to the transcendental equation.

Any help/guidance would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The non-zero solutions of $X''+\mu X = 0$ with $X(\pi)=0$ can be normalized so that $X'(\pi)=1$. The resoluting solution $X_{\mu}(x)$ has the form
$$
                    X_{\mu}(x) = \frac{\sin(\sqrt{\mu}(x-\pi))}{\sqrt{\mu}}.
$$
This is correct even for $\mu=0$ if you take the limiting case as $\mu\rightarrow 0$:
$$
                   X_{0}(x)=\lim_{\mu\rightarrow 0}X_{\mu}(x)=\lim_{\mu\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(\sqrt{\mu}(x-\pi)}{\sqrt{\mu}(x-\pi)}(x-\pi)=x-\pi.
$$
Using this form of $X_{\mu}(x)$
, the eigenvalue equation becomes
\begin{align}
            0 & =X_{\mu}(0)-hX_{\mu}'(0) \\
              & =\frac{\sin(\sqrt{\mu}(-\pi))}{\sqrt{\mu}}-h\cos(\sqrt{\mu}(-\pi)) \\
   & = -\frac{\sin(\sqrt{\mu}\pi)}{\sqrt{\mu}}-h\cos(\sqrt{\mu}\pi).
\end{align}
The solutions $\mu$ are the zeros of an entire function of $\mu$. Note that
$\mu=0$ is a solution iff $h=-\pi$. For $\mu\ne 0$, the the above may be written as the transcendental equation
$$
                \tan(\sqrt{\mu}\pi)=-h\sqrt{\mu}.
$$
If you plot both of these functions, you can graphically see the non-zero values of $\sqrt{\mu}$ that are solutions.